# C++ Preprocessor Macros and Return Statement

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to declare a C++ preprocessor macro for my methods

```
#define RETURN( expr... )
```

Where `RETURN` will return the expression (`return expr;`) if the expression is not empty or just call return (`return;`) without anything if the return type is void.

For instance I tried to do

```
#define RETURN( expr... ) if ( expr ) { return expr } return;
```

But if I place this in my program where it expects a non-void return type, it complains that the return-statement has no value because there's a single `return;` at the end. What is the proper way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What you are actually saying is `if expr evaluates to true then return the evaluated value of expr. If expr evaluates to false return nothing.`. How do you do it? You don't. If you need a return put one in. If you don't omit it.

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro for this?

Comment: I realize that, I played around with it because I'm not very familiar with C++ macros. What I want instead is for the compiler to examine if there is an expression declared, if it is invoke the `return` call on that expression otherwise just use normal `return`.

Comment: The idea was I was going to replace return entirely because there will be code called before anything is returned.

Comment: Wouldn't `#define RETURN(X) return X;` work?

Comment: *there will be code called before anything is returned* ... that's typically how functions work, what makes your case special that you need to use a macro? Anyway, I think you can use variadic macros for this - `#define RETURN(...) return __VA_ARGS__;`

Comment: Wow I can't believe it's that simple. Thanks it works.

Comment: *"I'm not very familiar with C++ macros."* That's probably not a bad thing. I do not say macros have no use in C++, but for most problems, the language offers better solutions you should learn first.

Comment: The use of this macro is part of a long coding exercise and it needs to be implemented even if I disagree with its approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define RETURN(...) return __VA_ARGS__
```

<s>You don't need to use variadic macros here, because they would just turn into the comma operator anyway</s>. As it turns out, you do want to use a variadic macros! Thanks @chris, I never thought of returning `{...}`.

Using it looks like:

```
void foo() {
    RETURN(); //return ;
}
int bar() {
    RETURN(0); //return 0;
}
float RunningOutOfFunctionNames() {
    RETURN(0, 'c', 2.0); //return 0, 'c', 2.0;
                           //AKA return 2.0;
}
std::pair<int, int> ThisOnlyWorksWithVariadicMacros() {
    RETURN({1, 2}); //return {1, 2};
}
```

I don't see a real use for this outside of some sort of macro factory that produces lots of boilerplate code.

Comment: Comma operator? [Not necessarily](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7f0556eb056b4ad).